# Change the last letter of a string

Tags: regex, sed

I'd like to use sed to change the last letter of a string in a text. For example, if I have

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sed felis maximus, mattis purus non, accumsan nunc.
```

I'd like to substitute all the last r by ɻ:

```
Lorem ipsum doloɻ sit amet, consectetuɻ adipiscing elit. In sed felis maximus, mattis purus non, accumsan nunc.
```

Notice that the non-last r in each word were kept in the final sentence.

I found a way to do it with the last character in a line, using .$, but not in a word.

Comment: use `\b` it is a word boundary. not sure if it work with sed though

Comment: @JorgeCampos yup, it works. `sed 's/r\b/X/g'`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/pK0zL6/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can address word boundaries using `\b`. The *last letter* is the letter before a word boundary.

This gives us the following command:

```
sed -r 's/r\b/ɻ/g' file
```

I'm saving the word boundary itself in capturing group 1, and replace the `r` by a `ɻ`.

Note that `\b` is a so called *zero width assertion*. Meaning that it has influence on the pattern in front of it (or behind it) but does not include characters into the match itself. Thanks to [Lucas Trzesniewski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002660/change-the-last-letter-of-a-string/33002777#comment53830518_33002777) for that!

Comment: `\b` is a zero-width assertion. No need to capture it, `\1` will always be an empty string.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thank you! Didn't knew that!